# react-redux with onClick display user on right

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need that after I click on button "Click" would appear "User {name} is here". What do I doing wrong here?

```
                        <td onClick={props.onHandleClick}>{item.user}</td>
                        <td type="button" 
                            className="btn btn-dark" 
                            data-id={Key} 
                            value={item} 
                            ref={this.user} 
                            onClick={props.onHandleUser}>Click</td>
                            {
                        <td >User"{item.user}" is here</td>
                            }
```

Comment: `"{item.user}"` is a string. You need `{item.user}` so that the JSX will [treat it as a javascript expression](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#javascript-expressions-as-children).

Comment: @BrianThompson I must take like "{item.user}"

Comment: I don't understand.. If you do it with quotes around it, it will not work. Why would you have to do it that way?

Answer (score 0):

```
     <td >User{item.user} is here</td>
```

Use this one while rendering username